# Apache throws 403 Forbidden after moving DocumentRoot (CentOS 6.4)

Tags: centos, permissions, apache-httpd

I installed Apache via yum on CentOS 6.4. I changed the `DocumentRoot` in `/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf` to point to `/home/djc/www`:

```
DocumentRoot "/home/djc/www"
<Directory "/home/djc/www">
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Directory>
```

FS permissions:

```
djc@vm ~ $ ls -l
drwxrwxr-x.  3 djc djc   4096 Jan 14 11:17 www
```

No SELinux:

```
djc@vm ~ $ sestatus
SELinux status:                 disabled
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For the new docroot to be accessible by Apache, the Apache users must be able to access all directories in the path leading up to `/home/djc/www`. So even though `/home/djc/www` is accessible to everyone, `/home/djc` must be executable by the Apache user. so for example if you have:

```
$ ls -ld ~
drwx------    1 djc   djc        0 Jan 13 15:16 /home/djc
```

You can make it accessible like this and it should be enough:

```
$ chmod o+x ~
$ ls -ld ~
drwx-----x    1 djc   djc        0 Jan 13 15:16 /home/djc
```